# Why does BufferedReader.read(char[]) appear to skip chars when read() does not?

Tags: java, json, io

I'm trying to use the `BufferedReader.read(char[])` method in lieu of the `read()` method for efficiency purposes but I'm noticing it's not reading all the chars for some reason and I'm not exactly sure what's wrong with my code. Code and output below:

FYI: `response` is of type `HttpUrlConnection`

//using `read(char[])`

```
 StringBuilder jsonResponse = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        //build the response
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getInputStream()));
            char[] chars = new char[2048];
            while ((reader.read(chars)) != -1) {
                jsonResponse.append(chars);
                chars = new char[2048];
            }

        } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                reader.close();
            }
        }
```

**output**: *(no ending quotation on "unique_id" value)*

```
        ...lots of json...
        "version": "2.4",
        "info_url": null,
        "active": true,
        "bindable": true,
        "unique_id": "8f4af9f9-0f29-4957-87a3-1039ce983ede
        "extra": "{\"listing\":{\"imageUrl\":null,\"blurb\":null},\"provider\":{\"name\":\"Core\"}}",
```

//using `read()`

```
StringBuilder jsonResponse = new StringBuilder();
BufferedReader reader = null;
//build the response
try {
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getInputStream()));
    int car = -1;
    while ((car = reader.read()) != -1) {
        jsonResponse.append((char)car);
    }

} finally {
    if (reader != null) {
        reader.close();
    }
}
```

**ouput**:*("unique_id" has an ending quote on value")*

```
         ...lots of json...
        "version": "2.4",
        "info_url": null,
        "active": true,
        "bindable": true,
        "unique_id": "8f4af9f9-0f29-4957-87a3-1039ce983ede",
        "extra": "{\"listing\":{\"imageUrl\":null,\"blurb\":null},\"provider\":{\"name\":\"Core\"}}",
```

Comment: I don't know if this has anything to do with it, but `jsonResponse.append(chars);` is appending all 2048 characters from `chars`, no matter how many were read, so if you happen to read less than 2048 characters, you'll have `nul`s scattered throughout `jsonResponse`. Instead, use something like `while ((i = reader.read(chars)) != -1) jsonResponse.append(chars, 0, i);` (untested, but should be close).

Comment: @blm yeah that seemed to do it, thanks! I'm not sure why the middle of the stream would be tainted with missing characters. I would think that the buffer would always be full up to to the last `read()` which might have less than 2048 chars

Comment: You've discovered an important detail of how blocking IO works in Java. The read methods of Reader and InputStream are not guaranteed to fill the buffers you pass; the only guarantee is that they will wait until they can return at least 1 byte / char (unless the end of stream is reached or an exception is thrown). It's worth reading the Javadoc for these methods very carefully.

Comment: You're welcome sreya. And @dnault is absolutely right. While it might seem like you should always get a full buffer (except at the end of course), there are a myriad of circumstances where you won't, and assuming you will will bite you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

only thing I can think of is this

```
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getInputStream()));
    char[] chars = new char[2048];
    int charsRead = 0;
    while ((charsRead = reader.read(chars)) != -1) {
        jsonResponse.append(chars, 0, charsRead);
        //no need to clear char[]
    }
```

Comment: Beat you by 27 seconds. ;-)

Comment: Or if you can use external libraries, Apache commons-io will do this for you in one line with the `IOUtils.toString` method. By the way, when converting bytes to characters it's good practice to specify the character encoding.